# Android 5.0 how to automatically obtain permissions when recording the screen?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojectionmanager

```java
MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
```

When sharing the screen, a window asking for permission will pop up.

I am looking for a way to automatically obtain all content (permissions) on the screen.

**I have root access to this device!**

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1):

If this is for testing where you have ADB access to the device – the media projection checks the `OP_PROJECT_MEDIA` AppOps ([code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/media/projection/MediaProjectionManagerService.java;l=267;drc=b3d4b64c0d2d95854ccfcfd4a7f6329b1258e2c1)), and you can enable it through ADB like this:

`adb shell cmd appops set <your.package.name> PROJECT_MEDIA allow`

Comment: Thanks ,I guess it might take Android 8+, so sad, my device is Android 7.1...

Comment: adb shell cmd appops set <your.package.name> PROJECT_MEDIA allow

Comment: Oh, It's work! Thanks!!